# Python tkinter Gui stops logic of Main class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have this kind of code where I wanted to add gui to my app and when I initiaze Main class the code runs till it hits Gui, then It open the gui window but the code won't go freely to the infinte loop unless I close the gui window.

My question is how to implement gui this main class so it to codes with the logic runs infinitely and the gui just display the data as it should

```
import gui as G
    
class Main:
    timeDelay = open("delay.txt", "r")
    global delay
    delay = int(timeDelay.read())
    def __init__(self):
        R.readTermMeter()
        X.checkTermMetersInDb(R.termListFromXml)
        P.getIdOfTeplomer(R.termListFromXml)



        G.Gui.__init__(self)
        gui = G.Gui()

        i = 5
        while i > 1:
            for item in R.termListFromXml:
                P.sendDataToDb(item)
            time.sleep(delay)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()


/////////

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()

        window.geometry("1053x1000")
        window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")


        canvas = Canvas(
            window,
            bg = "#FFFFFF",
            height = 1000,
            width = 1053,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        canvas.create_rectangle(
            580.0,
            0.0,
            1053.0,
            1000.0,
            fill="#1AACFF",
            outline="")

        canvas.create_text(
            98.0,
            42.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="last data: ",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("RobotoRoman Bold", 30 * -1)
        )

        canvas.create_rectangle(
            619.0,
            120.0,
            1015.0,
            815.0,
            fill="#E2E2E2",
            outline="")

        canvas.create_text(
            633.0,
            43.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="log:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("RobotoRoman Bold", 30 * -1)
        )

        button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
        button_1 = Button(
            image=button_image_1,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda:[print("button_1 clicked"),btnUpdateData()],
            relief="flat"
        )
        button_1.place(
            x=835.0,
            y=34.0,
            width=180.0,
            height=55.0
        )

        canvas.create_rectangle(
            35.0,
            123.0,
            527.0,
            183.0,
            fill="#D9D9D9",
            outline="")

        delkaListu = len(T.termListFromXml)
        i = int(delkaListu)




        for x, i in enumerate(T.termListFromXml):
                canvas.create_rectangle(
                    35.0,
                    123.0 + 70 * x,
                    213.0,
                    183.0 + 70 * x,
                    fill="#EB8888",
                    outline="")

                nameText = tkinter.Label(
                    text=i.name,
                    justify="center",
                    height="1",
                    font=("Georgia", int(16.0)),
                    bg="#EB8888"
                )
                nameText.place(
                    x=45,
                    y=138 + 70 * x,
                )



                canvas.create_rectangle(
                    213.0,
                    123.0 + 70 * x,
                    400.0,
                    183.0 + 70 * x,
                    fill="#7EB7EC",
                    outline="")


                ipText = tkinter.Label(
                    text=i.ip_add,
                    justify="center",
                    height="1",
                    font=("Georgia", int(16.0)),
                    bg="#7EB7EC"
                )
                ipText.place(
                    x=220,
                    y=138 + 70 * x,
                )

                if isinstance(i, O.Oboji):
                    canvas.create_rectangle(
                        400.0,
                        123.0 + 70 * x,
                        527.0,
                        183.0 + 70 * x,
                        fill="#FF4B4B",
                        outline="")

                    valueText = tkinter.Label(
                        text=i.teplotaValue,
                        justify="center",
                        height="1",
                        font=("Georgia", int(16.0)),
                        bg="#FF4B4B"
                    )
                    valueText.place(
                        x=410,
                        y=138 + 70 * x,
                    )
                    canvas.create_rectangle(
                        400.0,
                        123.0 + 70 * x,
                        527.0,
                        183.0 + 70 * x,
                        fill="#FF4B4B",
                        outline="")

                    valueText = tkinter.Label(
                        text=i.vlhkostValue,
                        justify="center",
                        height="1",
                        font=("Georgia", int(16.0)),
                        bg="#FF4B4B"
                    )
                    valueText.place(
                        x=410,
                        y=138 + 70 * x,
                    )

                else:
                    canvas.create_rectangle(
                        400.0,
                        123.0 + 70 * x,
                        527.0,
                        183.0 + 70 * x,
                        fill="#FF4B4B",
                        outline="")

                    valueText = tkinter.Label(
                        text="xx",
                        justify="center",
                        height="1",
                        font=("Georgia", int(16.0)),
                        bg="#FF4B4B"
                    )
                    valueText.place(
                        x=410,
                        y=138 + 70 * x,
                    )

        # for x in (T.termListFromXml):
            # canvas.itemconfigure(nameText,text=x.name)
            # nameText.configure(textvariable=x.name)

        def btnUpdateData():
            for x, i in enumerate(T.termListFromXml):
                if isinstance(i, O.Oboji):
                    print(i.teplotaValue)

                    print(i.vlhkostValue)



                else:
                    print(i.value)

        window.resizable(False, False)
        window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gui()
```

Comment: you have a lot of undefined variables. what is `R`, `X`, `P`, `G`?

Comment: these are references on other classes that do logic of gathering data, not needed to the problem with gui stopping functions below it

Comment: if using gui blocks your code, how is this not relevant? You are doing `G.Gui.__init__(self)` and `gui = G.Gui()` which we have no idea what is that. tkinter guis usually have a mainloop which might be blocking your code, but we cannot see your gui code

Comment: #edited so you can check gui class, the thing that there is G.Gui.__init__(self) and gui = G.Gui() is that I tried both of these differnt way of initializing the gui class (im sorry im new to all this kind of gui thing and calling one class from another :/ :(

Comment: yup. `window.mainloop()` there. your gui runs in a loop. Make an event to execute your code, or just execute the code before opening the gui. that code doesn;t seem to depend on the gui at all

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate the **init** stuff from the infinite loop you are trying to execute.

In the **init** method - only do stuff that needs to be done once.

In a **run** method - use a while True loop and put your logic in this loop.

Then, in the if **name** == '**main**' part, first, initialize your object, and on the next line, trigger its run method.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        runner = Main()
        Main.run()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried the change and it does the same thing. Initialize Gui and infinite loop works only after closing gui window..